# Remove checkbox label

Tags: magento2, checkbox, labels, documentation

Is there a way to remove a checkbox label from above?

[image]

I looked into documentation, but i didn't find any similar example.

Comment: can you show the code that generates the checkbox?

Comment: I actually found this on their main documentation http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_form.html. So my code is this default checkout xml.

Comment: magento 1.x or 2?

Comment: it's magento 2 .

Comment: post your custom form code

Comment: I attached the example above in link. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_form.html  It's default checkout_index.xml

Comment: @SlobodankaJovicic so from this link you have used static form ? - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_form.html#static-forms

Comment: @ManthanDave Yes, this <item name="checkbox_field" xsi:type="array"> - that block

Comment: @SlobodankaJovicic i have given answer please check

Answer (score 2):

You need to Remove **lable** item from your code

Remove **below Line** :

```
<item name="label" xsi:type="string">Checkbox Field</item>
```

Below is Complete  code :

```
<item name="checkbox_field" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/boolean</item>
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <!--customScope is used to group elements within a single form (e.g. they can be validated separately)-->
                        <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm</item>
                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/checkbox</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm.checkbox_field</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">3</item>
                </item>
```

Comment: Than both labels are gore and only checkbox is there. Is there a way to remove only one of them?

Answer (score 1):

Use this "description" instead of "label"

"label":

```
<item name="label">I accept the Terms of Use and Privacy Policy</item>
```

"description":

```
<item name="description" xsi:type="string">I accept the Terms of Use and Privacy Policy</item>
```

preference: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12125